# class not found exception in openshift

Tags: java, bash, shell, openshift

Am running this command below in a shell script, it works on windows but can't identify why its not working in the sheell script in openshift. I have the `.class` files in that folder.

```
export JARPATH=$(JARS=("$LIB"/*.jar); IFS=:; echo "${JARS[*]}")

nohup javac -classpath $JARPATH $MATCHFACES/*.java > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/compile.log 2>&1 &
// the above works without errors

cd $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR"src/matchfaces"

nohup java -classpath $JARPATH matchfaces.Listener > ${OPENSHIFT_DIY_LOG_DIR}/Listener.log 2>&1 &
// the above spits the error below
```

The error I get is

> Error: Could not find or load main class .var.lib.openshift.586b985a89r3cfe9fa1111bc.app-root.runtime.repo.src.matchfaces.Listener

Listener.java source code

```
package matchfaces;

import Luxand.FSDK;

/**
 *
 * @author daviestobialexz
 */
public class Listener {

 public static final String JAVABRIDGE_PORT = "1699";//8080
static final php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner runner =
        php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner.getInstance(JAVABRIDGE_PORT);
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.lang.InterruptedException
 */
public static void main(  String[] args ) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    try {
            System.loadLibrary("facesdk");
            int res = FSDK.ActivateLibrary("OYVHSxkUjwoYalZqg=");
            FSDK.Initialize();
            FSDK.SetFaceDetectionParameters(true, true, 384);
            FSDK.SetFaceDetectionThreshold(5);

            if (res == FSDK.FSDKE_OK) {
                    System.out.printf("FaceSDK activated", "FaceSDK activated\n");
            } else {
                     System.out.printf("Error activating FaceSDK: ", res + "\n");
            }
    } catch (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
             System.out.printf("exception ", e.getMessage());
    }
    try{
    runner.waitFor();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.printf("Error: ", ex.getMessage() + "\n");
    }
    // System.exit(0);
}

}
```

Comment: if the environment variable doesn't contain confidential information, could you please provide the value of `JARPATH` ? Also your class `Listener` is the package `.var.lib.openshift.586b985a89r3cfe9fa1111bc.app-root.runtime.repo.src.matchfaces`, the package starts with a `.` which is not correct.

Comment: @MickaëlB The jar path contains an array list of `.jar` files that is needed to compile and run the java file. check update

Comment: If you have the source code of `Listener` class, could you please provide the package of this class ? Also, you should provide the complete stacktrace of your error.

Comment: @MickaëlB the source code is in the new edit and as for the stack trace thats all it says the error above.